# Atom snippet for HTML comments

Tags: code-snippets, atom-editor

I was looking through the atom documentation at writing snippets:

[Using atom snippets](https://atom.io/docs/v1.1.0/using-atom-snippets)

However, the documentation is too simple for the problem I'm facing. I want to write a snippet that will automatically create a comment that will contain a class name of the HTML element. Let's see an example:

```
<div class="first-class another-class">

  ...

</div><!-- first-class another-class -->
```

I want to have a snippet that will automatically create the comment containing "first-class another-class" when I type, for instance, "comm" after the closing tag of the div and hit TAB. Is this even possible with snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't your workflow allow you to create the comment together with the preceding tag? In that case, you could use something like this:

```
'.text.html':
  'Snippet Name':
    'prefix': 'comm'
    'body': """
      <div class="${1:classes}">
        ${2:<!-- your markup here -->}
      </div><!-- ${1:classes} -->
    """
```

Or more advanced:

```
'.text.html':
  'div+comment':
    'prefix': 'comm'
    'body': """
      <${1:div} ${2:class="${3:classes}"}>
        ${4:<!-- your markup here -->}
      </${1:div}>${2:<!-- ${3:classes} -->}
    """
```

Save this file as (e.g. `comm.cson`) and put it in the packages directory.

Comment: That's what I call 'out of box' thinking :) sounds awesome, thanks very much.

Comment: There was a mistake in the second script, should be fixed now!